# Adding sparse matrices with explicit column and row order and different shapes

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Let's say I have two sparse matrices, `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` to be precise, that I would like to add element-wise, with the added problem that they have an ID to each row and column, corresponding to a word.

For instance, one matrix might have columns and rows that correspond to `['cat', 'hat']`, in that particular order. Another matrix could then have columns and rows that correspond to `['cat', 'mat', 'hat']`. This means that when adding these matrices, I need to take into account the following things:

1. The matrices might have corresponding columns and rows in different orders.
2. The matrices might not be of the same shape.
3. Some columns and rows in one matrix might be not be present in the other.

I have trouble coming up with a solution to this merging problem, and would hope that you could help me come up with an answer.

For added clarity, here's an example:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
mat1_id2column = ['cat', 'hat']
mat1_id2row = ['cat', 'hat']
mat2_id2column = ['cat', 'mat', 'hat']
mat2_id2row = ['cat', 'mat', 'hat']

mat1 = sp.csr_matrix([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
mat2 = sp.csr_matrix([[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]])

merge(mat1, mat2)

#Expected output: 
id2column = ['cat', 'hat', 'mat']
id2row = ['cat', 'hat', 'mat']
merged = sp.csr_matrix([[2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]])
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is it important that the array is sparse?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using sparse matricies, and `csr` in particular?  Seems to me that this data could be coded just as well as Python dictionary.  The keys would be pairs of strings.  If  sparse matricies are convenient for some operations, use a unique mapping between strings and indexes to make `dok_matrix`.

Comment: @hpaulj and Bitwise: Yes, it is important. This is a dummy example - my real world matrices have up to 100k rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

Start by building a row id index that will be the union of the row ids of the 2 matrices. Then do the same for columns. Using this, you can now translate from coordinates in the old matrices to coordinates in the new result matrix.

Do you see how to finish it from there or should I be more explicit?

Comment: Yes, I have been thinking about this method as well, but since I have a lot of values to iterate over I was hoping for some suitable optimized operations to speed it up considerably. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

In one way of other you have to work out a unique mapping from your strings and row/column indexes.

A start using dictionaries is:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def foo(dd,mat):
    for ij,v in mat[0].todok().iteritems():
        dd[(mat[1][ij[0]],mat[2][ij[1]])] += v

dd=defaultdict(int)
foo(dd,(mat1,mat1_id2row,mat1_id2column))
foo(dd,(mat2,mat2_id2row,mat2_id2column))
print dd
```

produces

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('cat', 'hat'): 1, 
                           ('hat', 'hat'): 2, 
                           ('mat', 'cat'): 1, 
                           ('cat', 'cat'): 2})
```

`dd` could then be turned back into a `dok`

---

A different approach would take advantage of the way `coo_matrix` handles duplicates - they are added together when it is converted to a `csr`.

In this example take `['cat', 'mat', 'hat']` as the master index.

The 2 defining arrays for `mat2` are then

```
data: array([1, 1, 1, 1])
row : array([0, 0, 1, 2])
col : array([0, 2, 0, 2])
```

for `mat1` they would be (I haven't worked out the code to do this yet)

```
data: array([1, 1])
row : array([0, 2])
col : array([0, 2])
```

concatenate the respective arrays, and create a new `coo` matrix `merged`

```
data: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
row : array([0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2])
col : array([0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2])
```

`merged.A` would be

```
array([[2, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2]])
```

---

another option is to use matrix multiplication to map the arrays on to larger ones that can be added.  Again I'm leaving the details of how to generate the mapping unspecified.  You'd have to generate a separate `T` for each different sequence of words.  That may require the same amount of iterative work as the other approaches.

```
T1 = sp.csr_matrix(np.array([[1,0],[0,0],[0,1]]))
T2 = T1.T # same mapping for row and cols of mat1
T1.dot(mat1).dot(T2) + mat2
```